# How not to repeat duplicate values using select form control

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a view where it has a multiple-select list option for the user. I wanted to select the department in my select list but I have a problem here where I join the `departments` from `users` but I wanted to show only once the `department_name` in my select list.

I have a one to many relationship. **`departments`** and **`users`**

[image: SC]

**Join statement**

```
$resultRecipient = DB::table('users')->select('users.username', 'departments.department_name', 'users.id')
    ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'users.department_id')->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($resultRecipient as $list)
    <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
    <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

[image: SC1]

How can avoid the repeating values of `department_name` in my select? Any help or tips will appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Lets say I have users named A, B and C belongs to Department of IT and users named D, E belongs to Department of Engr. What I wanted to show in my view is all the users and all the departments. So the values of select list will be.

A

B

C

D

E

Department of IT

Department of Engr

Comment: add `group by user.id` in your query but it will gave only one department per user and that is not correct because your user belongs to more than one department

Comment: can we see the full structure of users ?

Comment: What's your desired output in the view? Do you want the department name showing beside only the first person from each department?

Comment: @VasilShaddix Please see my updated post..

Comment: @Jason I wanted to show all the department also the user. But I'm having a problem where I get all the department instead of one.

Comment: @Anant I updated my full structure of users please see.

Comment: @Francisunoxx You want to show for each user their department ? For ex. Francis, Mia, Department of IT ... ?

Answer (score 0):

The result `$resultRecipient` contains a list of all users, with the department name attached to each user. There will be duplicate department names becuase there could be multiple users in one department.

To get a clean list of department names, you would need a separate query:

```
$departments = DB::table('departments')->get();
```

And in the view

```
@foreach ($departments as $d)
    <option value = "{{ $d->id }}">{{ $d->department_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**UPDATE 1**

So you want a list of all users plus department names.

First, get all users and all departments and store them into an array:

```
$departments = DB::table('departments')->select('id, department_name as name')->get();
$users = DB::table('users')->select('id, username as name')->get();
$list = $departments + $users;
```

Second, update the view:

```
@foreach ($list as $item)
    <option value = "{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How can I show my users and departments in my select? If this was only retrieve via department_name not users. I wanted to show in my view the users and department.

Comment: Your original code does just that. You just need to add in the user names, so the dropdown shows: username - department_name. And there should be duplicate department names becuase there are more than one users in the same department

Comment: I get your point. It select all the users from department. But how can I avoid the duplication of department_name?

Comment: Could you draw a picure of the desired output?

Comment: I elaborate my expected output please see.

Comment: I tried this but in the `{{ $item->name }}` gives me a error `Undefined property: stdClass::$name` I think laravel confuse dont know which one will be show in the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120669/discussion-between-jason-and-francisunoxx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the users and under every user, their department you will have to do it with php.

You can still user your query, but then you have to do something like this.

```
$dict = [];
$returnArray = [];
foreach($resultRecipient as $key => $queryResult) {
    $departmentName = $queryResult->department_name; 
    $userId = $queryResult->id;
    $userName = $queryResult->username;

    if (! isset($dict[$departmentName])) {
        $returnArray[] = array(
            'department_name' => $departmentName,
            'users' => [],
        );
        $index = count($returnArray) - 1;

        $dict[$departmentName] = array(
            'pointer' => & $returnArray[$index]['users']
        );
    }

    $dict[$departmentName]['pointer'][$userId] = $userName;
}
```

Now in your `$returnArray` you have a structure looking like this

```
{
    [
        "department_name" : "xxxxx",
        "users" : {
            "userId1" : "name1",
            "userId2" : "name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the view you can loop them

```
@foreach ($returnArray as $list)
    @foreach ($list['users'] as $userId => $username)
        <option value = "{{ $userId }}">{{ $username }}</option>
    @endforeach

    <option value = "{{ $list['department_name'] }}">{{ $list['department_name'] }}</option>
@endforeach
```

I am not familiar with the laravel view syntax, you may need to change something a bit.

This will print every user which is assigned to a department, after that the department name.

### -EDIT:

For the view you want just make 2 queries, one for the users and one for the departments:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$departments = DB::table('departments')->get();
```

In the view just do something like this:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <option value = "{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->username }}</option>
@endforeach

@foreach ($departments as $department)
    <option value = "{{ $department->id }}">{{ $department->department_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm also thinking of this showing them in view in separate. But is it possible if I choose one of the value in departments. And I want to insert a query all the users that selected by in department?

Comment: Yes, you can select all the users which are in the same department.

Comment: But how can I show in my select only the users registered with department_id? Because what you did you just select the department_name. Is there a way how can I do this?

Comment: This is not related to your question. If you want that to be answered, ask another one.